# C# Shared Memory - risk of CPU caching (non-volatile reads)?

Tags: c#, shared-memory, compiler-optimization, cpu-architecture, memory-barriers

I'm wondering about the implementation of shared memory in C#. MemoryMappedViewAccessor lets you read data from a shared memory region.

Now, memoryMappedViewAccessor inherits from UnmanagedMemoryAccessor, which exopses methods such as ReadInt32(), whose imlementation can be seen here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/unmanagedmemoryaccessor.cs,7632fe79d4a8ae4c . In principle, it seems to use relatively simple unsafe pointer arithmetic/casting,

```
 pointer += (_offset + position);
 result = *((Int32*)(pointer));
```

But .. (how) is it guaranteed the CPU wouldn't cache this value?
As in, you can mark variables with "volatile" to ensure this behavior, but how's that managed in a case as above, where data is read from memory by pointer via unsafe code. Would that always be treated as a volatile read, or is it not volatile?

In case of the latter, wouldn't that mean that shared memory data may get out of sync in Microsoft's implementation - e.g. an external process overrides a certain memory location very frequently, and C# code reads this very frequently, risking for values to be CPU cached instead of newly read from memory each time?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) (C and x86 asm) explains cache coherency and what happens when multiple CPUs are reading / writing the same location.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the link, Peter. I'm not 100% sure about my own answer and my comments under it, can you see any errors in them?

Comment: @HadiBrais: I don't know C# at all, but it looked reasonable when I read it.  But I think the main point is that you want to stop the compiler from "caching" the value in a *register* and not doing another load at all.  It's not important whether or not you micro-architecturally *could* have two real loads merged, just that they both happened separately.  i.e. cache is coherent, so CPU caching is not a risk in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of the code `*((Int32*)(pointer))` gets compiled to a machine instruction that accesses a memory location. So each time `ReadInt32` is called, the specified memory location will be accessed. If by "is it guaranteed the CPU wouldn't cache this value?" you are referring to the CPU caches, then cache coherence implemented in hardware will ensure that the up-to-date value is accessed. Otherwise, if you are referring to the internal buffering structures used to hold loaded data until the instruction that issued the load retires, then once the load retires, any other subsequent loads to the same memory location will have to send another memory request to the cache hierarchy (the internal buffers no longer contain the data).

That said, two loads that are close enough in the instruction sequence and that access the same memory location may get combined (assuming the CPU supports such technique) if there are no load serialization instructions (load barrier) between them. *I don't think* that will ever happen with a large function like `ReadInt32` (taking into account also all the code of the functions `ReadInt32` calls). Even by calling `ReadInt32` consecutively without any code between the calls, there will be hundreds of instructions between the two consecutive `*((Int32*)(pointer))` accesses with all kinds of dependencies, the chance of combining the two reads is practically zero on all x86 and ARM processors. The processor would have retired the first read long before it sees the second one. Note that two consecutive reads can be combined into a single memory request.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation! Is my interpretation of your reply correct that say, if e.g. unsafe C# executes *((Int32*)(pointer)) twice in a row, e.g. reads memory (say, not with any function calls in between but directly/subsequently), and the value stored in that address is being changed externally just in between those 2 reads (e.g. shared memory being written by another process), C# would guaranteed to read the latest value on each call IF it is guaranteed that the compiler doesn't do any re-arranging/combining of those read statements?

Comment: @Bogey Rearranging two reads to the same location (by the compiler or the CPU (legal on ARM processors but not x86)) with no instructions in between may have an impact on the correctness on the program. That's because the second read in program order may get an older value than the first read in program order in case they were rearranged. Combing reads is legal on both ARM and x86 processors and can delay fetching an updated value. Therefore, the guarantee is only that *eventually* you'll get the latest value but it's not guaranteed which read access is going to do that...

Comment: @Bogey ...and when that's going to happen. That can only be controlled by using read barriers. Otherwise, the reads are considered to be concurrent with any other accesses from other cores. However, cache coherence ensures that any accesses to any of the caches from any of the cores will be coherent (will see the same and latest value).